# Error calling DLL with Unicode Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, dll, unicode, parameter-passing

I have a DLL with this **function signature**:

```
function KP_RecuperarDadosFabricante(EnderecoIp, ChaveAcesso, 
  Porta: string; Return: PAnsiChar): Integer; stdcall; external 'Key.dll';
```

This is the sample VB.NET code from the manual of the dll:

```
Dim ret As Integer 
Dim ptrStr As IntPtr 
Dim DadosFab As String 

ptrStr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(256) 
ret = KP_RecuperarDadosFabricante("192.168.1.201", "0", "4370", ptrStr) 
DadosFab = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptrStr)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrStr)
```

This is my Delphi code:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Return: string;
  pReturn: PAnsiChar;
begin
  GetMem(pReturn, 512);
  FillChar(pReturn^, 512, 0);
  Memo1.Text:='';
  if KP_RecuperarDadosFabricante("192.168.1.201", "0", "4370", pReturn) = 1 then
  begin
    Return := StrPas(pReturn);
    ShowMessage(Return);
  end
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('Error');
  end;
end;
```

This code **works well in Delphi 7**, **but not works in Delphi XE**. It always returns "Error".
How to make this code works in **Delphi XE**?

Comment: the **far** directive is deprecated since... mmmm, maybe since Delphi 3 if not Delphi 1, why are you using it? what about freeing the memory you get? The vb example frees it, but your code leaks 512 bytes per call!

Comment: @jachguate I removed "far" code, but not solved the problem. The memory is not problem yet. thanks

Comment: I didn't say it solves your problem, but they are other _problems_ you have.

Comment: You need to show the p/invoke declaration too.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In Delphi 7 it works with this code, I don't have more code. But I don't know how to work with P/Invoke. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: We need to see the VB code which defines `KP_RecuperarDadosFabricante`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK. I will request this code to the device manufacturer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the DLL was written in Delphi 7, then you cannot use that DLL from Delphi XE. Even if you change the `string` parameters to `AnsiString` to make the character sizes the same, you're still stuck with the fact that the internal structure of strings changed somewhere between those versions, so the `AnsiString` you send from the Delphi XE code will not look the way the Delphi 7 code expects an `AnsiString` to look.

If you have the power to change and recompile the DLL, you should make the parameters be `PAnsiChar` instead, just like you'd see from nearly any other DLL on Windows. Also remember to change the final `PChar` parameter to `PAnsiChar`.

---

If the DLL was written in some non-Delphi language, then you might be able to fix it simply by changing the function signature. Non-Delphi languages don't have Delphi's `string` type, so the declaration was wrong all the time; you were just lucky when it worked from Delphi 7. Change all the parameters to have type `PAnsiChar` (including the final parameter); then they'll match the `char*` type they probably have from the original C code.

Comment: +1. Never expose anything from a DLL other than very basic non-Delphi specific types like 8, 16, 32 and 64 bit integers, 32 bit and 64 bit floating point types, records containing such types and pointers.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I changed the signature from Pchar to PAnsiChar, but I don't solved the problem. This is the sample code from the manual of the dll, in VB.NET: >>>  Dim ret As Integer
Dim ptrStr As IntPtr
Dim DadosFab As String
ptrStr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(256)
ret = KP1510_RecuperarDadosFabricante("192.168.1.201", "0", "4370",
ptrStr)
DadosFab =
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptrStr)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrStr)

Comment: I do not know if the DLL was written in Delphi 7

Comment: It's not enough just to change the PChar parameter to PAnsiChar. I told you to change the *string* parameters to that type, too.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I did this, and already updated my code in question. Could you suggest some other solution?

Comment: @dataol: The sample call should have been in your original question. I've added it, but next time this type of information is important to include when you ask a question (in the question itself, not in comments where people might or might not see it).